# $_GET does store my data but $_POST does not, why?

Tags: php, html, post, get

I am trying to submit my data with the `$_POST` method but my data doesn't get to the next page. When I use `$_GET`, my data does get through. How can I solve this?

My code:

```
    <form class="aanmelden" method="GET" action="login_verwerken.php">
        <h1>Aanmelden</h1>
        <label for="e_mail">E-mail:</label>
        <input type="text" id="e_mail" name="email" placeholder="E-mailadres" autofocus required>
        <label for="wachtwoord">Wachtwoord:</label>
        <input type="password" id="wachtwoord" name="wachtwoord" placeholder="Wachtwoord" required>
        <input type="checkbox" id="gegevens" name="onthouden">
        <label for="gegevens">Inloggegevens onhouden</label>
        <input type="submit" value="Aanmelden">
        <a href="registreren_persoonlijke_gegevens.php"><h2 class="registreren">Registreren</h2></a>
    </form>
```

The result when I use `$_GET` as method:
    [image: -]

The result when I use `$_POST`:
    [image]

The code of the page where `$_GET` and `$_POST` data is being sent:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    require_once('../dbInfo.php');

    $mailadres = $_GET['email'];
    $wachtwoord = $_GET['wachtwoord'];

    echo $mailadres;
    echo $wachtwoord;

    $query = "SELECT gebruikersnaam FROM gebruikers WHERE emailAdres = '$mailadres' AND wachtwoord = '$wachtwoord' ";

    $data = $dbh->query($query);
    $test = $data->fetch();



    if ($row = $test[0]){
        $_SESSION['naam'] = $test[0];
        header('Location: ../login/filmoverzicht.php');
        //echo "gelukt";
        //echo $_SESSION['naam'];
    }else {
        echo "Login niet gelukt!";
        header('Location: ../public/home_page.php');
    }  
    ?>
```

Can someone help me out?

Comment: I'm sorry, when I put the code in the textfield it automatically renders as html code, I don't know how to stop this. So therefore code in images.

Comment: what ??? how did you taken the screenshot ?? and from where ? same place you need to use ctrl+c and v . what's the big deal there ?

Comment: Just copy and paste your code then select all of them and `Ctrl + K` or click`{ }` symbol ?

Comment: So, you want to save the above form data using `POST` method ?

Comment: Yes! I want to take the from the form, from the first page to the second page. And I want to do this with $_POST. I can send my data to the next page when I use $_GET, but when I use $_POST my variables stay empty.

Answer (score 1):

### Change form method GET to POST and then try as shown below

```
<form class="aanmelden" method="POST" action="">
    <h1>Aanmelden</h1>
    <label for="e_mail">E-mail:</label>
    <input type="text" id="e_mail" name="email" placeholder="E-mailadres" autofocus required>
    <label for="wachtwoord">Wachtwoord:</label>
    <input type="password" id="wachtwoord" name="wachtwoord" placeholder="Wachtwoord" required>
    <input type="checkbox" id="gegevens" name="onthouden">
    <label for="gegevens">Inloggegevens onhouden</label>
    <input type="submit" value="Aanmelden">
    <a href="registreren_persoonlijke_gegevens.php"><h2 class="registreren">Registreren</h2></a>
</form>


<?php 

if(isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST)) {

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($_POST);
}


?>
```

Comment: Why do you need to add `isset($_POST)` ? I think `!empty($_POST)` does all the work needed.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite obvious that you used `$_GET` in your code. You won't get any POST value from that. You should use `$_POST`:

```
$mailadres = $_POST['email'];
$wachtwoord = $_POST['wachtwoord'];
```

In the HTML, you should change from `method="get"` to `method="post"`.

Besides, do not use `$_GET` or `$_POST` values directly in your query. You should escape or clean the variable first.

Last, in your `if` case (`if ($row = $test[0])`), you should use `==` instead of `=`.

Comment: I know that I used $_GET in my form, in the code above. When I change $_GET to $_POST, it doesn't work. Thanks for your suggestions

Comment: Please define doesn't work. What's the output of `var_dump($_POST)` ?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting data from `$_GET` this happened because you have mentioned `method` as a `GET`. It should be `method="POST"`

```
<form class="aanmelden" method="GET" action="login_verwerken.php">
```

OR

```
<form class="aanmelden" action="login_verwerken.php">
```

Above form tags will use method `GET`. If you do not mention `method` in the form tag it will take `method="GET"` by default. To send data with `POST` you have to use `method="POST"` in your form tag.

```
<form class="aanmelden" method="POST" action="login_verwerken.php">
```

One more thing. [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) can be done with your query below. You have used `$mailadres` and `$wachtwoord` directly with query.

```
$query = "SELECT gebruikersnaam FROM gebruikers WHERE emailAdres = '$mailadres' AND wachtwoord = '$wachtwoord' ";
```

To prevent [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) you can use parameterized query.